# PyForms GUI: ImportError: /../PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyforms

I am trying to understand what `pyforms` can offer me. I am running one basic example: [link](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0/getting-started/the-basic/#the-basic). I am running into issues. No success so far. I am running it on the Kaggle browser notebook.

code:

```
!pip install pyforms
import pyforms
from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
from   pyforms.controls import ControlText
from   pyforms.controls import ControlButton

class SimpleExample1(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleExample1,self).__init__('Simple example 1')

        #Definition of the forms fields
        self._firstname     = ControlText('First name', 'Default value')
        self._middlename    = ControlText('Middle name')
        self._lastname      = ControlText('Lastname name')
        self._fullname      = ControlText('Full name')
        self._button        = ControlButton('Press this button')


#Execute the application
if __name__ == "__main__":   pyforms.start_app( SimpleExample1 )
```

present output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install pyforms')
----> 2 import pyforms
      3 from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
      4 from   pyforms.controls import ControlText

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyforms/__init__.py:28
     21 conf += 'pyforms.settings'
     26 if conf.PYFORMS_MODE == 'GUI':
---> 28     from pyforms_gui.appmanager import start_app
     30 elif conf.PYFORMS_MODE == 'TERMINAL':
     32     from pyforms_terminal.appmanager import start_app

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyforms_gui/appmanager.py:4
      1 #!/usr/bin/python
      2 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 4 from pyforms_gui.controls.control_dockwidget import ControlDockWidget
      5 from AnyQt.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QAction, QApplication, QToolBar
      6 from AnyQt           import QtCore, _api

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyforms_gui/controls/control_dockwidget.py:4
      1 #!/usr/bin/python
      2 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 4 from pyforms_gui.controls.control_emptywidget import ControlEmptyWidget
      7 class ControlDockWidget(ControlEmptyWidget):
      8     SIDE_LEFT = 'left'

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyforms_gui/controls/control_emptywidget.py:7
      4 from confapp import conf
      6 from AnyQt                              import _api
----> 7 from AnyQt.QtWidgets                    import QWidget, QVBoxLayout
      8 from pyforms_gui.controls.control_base  import ControlBase
      9 from pyforms_gui.basewidget             import BaseWidget

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AnyQt/QtWidgets.py:222
    220     QStyle.SubControls = QStyle.SubControl
    221 elif _api.USED_API == _api.QT_API_PYQT5:
--> 222     from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    223     from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION as _PYQT_VERSION
    225     if _PYQT_VERSION < 0x50502:  # ?

ImportError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5
```